# Random char in tsql string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to replace all `?` symbols with random letters or numbers.

So I tried this:

```
REPLACE (RGFLT, '?', LEFT(NEWID(), 1))
```

This code is not good enough, because it generate random symbol once per each row. What I need is random symbol for every `?` in string.

Data sample:

```
AA ?????
BCZ ???Z?
B?? ???
```

Comment: SQL does row by row operations. we cannot assign two types to one symbol in a row

Comment: So its impossible to replace this string `ABC ???` with `'ABC ' + 3 random symbols` ?

Comment: Where are located the question marks ? always together and at the same place ? Could you give more sample data of RGFLT ?

Comment: AFAIK..it is imp to replace with multiple symbols but can with single symbol. \

Comment: Are you trying to update the data or you just need to `SELECT` it in the new format?

Comment: I need to `SELECT` it in new format in order to `INSERT` it to another table.

Comment: Maximum length of `RGFLT`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setup data

```
DECLARE @t table (
   a varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @t (a)
  VALUES ('A?A??')
       , ('BBBBB')
       , ('C??CC')
       , ('??DD?')
       , ('?????')
       , ('?')
       , ('ABCDEF??ASG?AG?GE?E?£%$ H?EHH?SN?S SA? ? !??" ')
;
```

---

### Method 1 - Recursive CTE

```
; WITH x AS (
  SELECT a As original_value
       , numbers.number As sequence
       , SubString(a, numbers.number, 1) As to_replace
       , Left(NewID(), 1) As replace_char
  FROM   @t As t
   LEFT
    JOIN dbo.numbers
      ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND Len(t.a)
)
, y AS (
  SELECT original_value
       , sequence
       , CASE WHEN to_replace = '?' THEN replace_char ELSE to_replace END As to_use
  FROM   x As x1
)
, z AS (
  SELECT original_value
       , sequence
       , to_use
       , Cast(to_use As varchar(max)) As new_value
  FROM   y
  WHERE  sequence = 1 -- anchor

   UNION ALL

    SELECT z.original_value
         , y.sequence
         , y.to_use
         , z.new_value + y.to_use
    FROM   z
     INNER
      JOIN y
        ON y.original_value = z.original_value
       AND y.sequence - 1 = z.sequence
)
SELECT original_value
     , new_value
FROM   z
WHERE  sequence = Len(original_value)
;
```

### [Example] Results:

```
original_value                                     new_value
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
?                                                  F
ABCDEF??ASG?AG?GE?E?£%$ H?EHH?SN?S SA? ? !??"      ABCDEF4DASG7AGFGE5E2£%$ H7EHHASN2S SAF 1 !77"
?????                                              CB347
??DD?                                              43DD2
C??CC                                              C31CC
BBBBB                                              BBBBB
A?A??                                              A7A99
```

Here's the jist of how it works:

1. Use a numbers table to split the original value in to a single row per character.
2. Work out which strings we want to replace (`?`) and generate a random character for these. For those we don't want to replace, keep the original character.
3. Use recursion to basically build the string back together 1 character at a time
4. Filter to show the "final" value

---

### Method 2 - Stuff(FORXML)

```
; WITH x AS (
  SELECT a As original_value
       , numbers.number As sequence
       , SubString(a, numbers.number, 1) As to_replace
       , Left(NewID(), 1) As replace_char
  FROM   @t As t
   LEFT
    JOIN dbo.numbers
      ON numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND Len(t.a)
)
, y AS (
  SELECT original_value
       , sequence
       , CASE WHEN to_replace = '?' THEN replace_char ELSE to_replace END As to_use
  FROM   x As x1
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       original_value
     , Replace(Stuff((
         SELECT '|' + z.to_use
         FROM   y As z
         WHERE  z.original_value = y.original_value
         ORDER
             BY z.sequence
         FOR XML PATH(''))
       , 1, 1, ''), '|', '') As new_value
FROM   y
;
```

### [Example] Results:

```
original_value                                     new_value
-------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------
?                                                  5
?????                                              10A30
??DD?                                              7EDDC
A?A??                                              AEA23
ABCDEF??ASG?AG?GE?E?£%$ H?EHH?SN?S SA? ? !??"      ABCDEFE8ASGEAG0GEBE4£%$ H8EHH2SNCS SAE 1 !1E"
BBBBB                                              BBBBB
C??CC                                              C34CC
```

Here's the jist of how it works:

Steps 1 & 2 same as method 1...

3. Use the [yucky!] `Stuff(FOR XML)` hack used for string concatenation to brute force the values back together in to a single string value.

Not pretty, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Note that I have made the following assumptions

- the max count of sequence `?` characters is `5`
- if you get two equal counts of `?` sequences there are going to be replaced with same numbers. For example, the text  `TEST ?? TEST ??` is going to be transformed like this `TEST 12 TEST 12`

AS the solution is not dynamic (you need to change it to work in your case).

---

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Text] VARCHAR(128)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Text])
VALUES ('AA ?????')
      ,('BCZ ???Z?')
      ,('B?? ???')
      ,('C?? ???')
      ,('D?? ???');


SELECT [Text]
      ,REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE([Text], '?????', LEFT(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 100000, 5))
                    , '????',LEFT(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 100000, 4))
                , '???',LEFT(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 100000, 3))
            , '??',LEFT(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 100000, 2))
        , '?',LEFT(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000000 + 100000, 1))
FROM @DataSource;
```